# R Shiny: need consistent random sample with each customization

Tags: r, shiny, random

This is my first ever question, so apologies in advance if I don't follow any of the site's norms!

I'm experimenting with R Shiny. I am attempting to make an application that allows someone to customize a lot of the components of different distributions and kernel estimators. Before I go any further, however, my issue is this: **Every time I adjust one of the sliders or other customizable options in my app, an entirely new sample is drawn. How can I use one sample without changing it if I, for example, want to decrease my kernel bandwidth?**

Right now I have the following `ui.R` and `server.R` codes:

```
    library(shiny)
    shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
      headerPanel("Kernel Estimation"),
      mainPanel(
      sliderInput(inputId = "n_breaks",
          label = "Number of bins in histogram (approximate):",
          min = 1,
          max = 50,
          value = 25),

      sliderInput(inputId = "observations",
         label = "Number of observations:",
         min = 10,
         max = 1000,
         value = 500),

      checkboxInput(inputId = "density",
            label = strong("Show density estimate"),
            value = FALSE),

      # Display this only if the density is shown
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.density == true",
               sliderInput(inputId = "bw_adjust",
                           label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
                           min = 0.2, max = 2, value = 1, step = 0.2)),

      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.density == true",
               selectInput(inputId = "kernel",
                           label = "Type of Kernel:",
                           list("Gaussian" = "gaussian", "Epanechnikov" = "epanechnikov", "Rectangular" = "rectangular", "Triangular" = "triangular", "Biweight" = "biweight", "Optcosine" = "optcosine"))),

      checkboxInput(inputId = "individual_obs",
            label = strong("Show individual observations"),
            value = FALSE),

      plotOutput(outputId = "main_plot", height = "300px")

    )))
```

aaaaaand also:

```
    library(shiny)

    shinyServer(function(input, output) {

      output$main_plot <- renderPlot({
        hist(rnorm(input$observations,mean=0,sd=1),
     probability = TRUE,
     breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
     xlab = "Observations",
     main = "Standard Normal Distribution")

if (input$individual_obs) {
  rug(rnorm(input$observations,mean=0,sd=1), col = "red")
}

if (input$density) {
  dens <- density(rnorm(input$observations,mean=0,sd=1),
                  kernel = input$kernel,
                  adjust = input$bw_adjust)
  lines(dens, col = "blue")
}

      })
    })
```

which yield.. oh, crap. I haven't been a member long enough to post images. I'll try to post [this link](http://127.0.0.1:7150/), but I don't know if that will take you to my app or not.

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: See the help file for `set.seed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem can be solved by generating the distribution in a reactive function like so:

```
get_observations <- reactive(
{
    return(rnorm(input$observations,mean=0,sd=1))
})

if (input$individual_obs) {
  rug(get_observations(), col = "red")
}

if (input$density) {
  dens <- density(get_observations(),
                  kernel = input$kernel,
                  adjust = input$bw_adjust)
  lines(dens, col = "blue")
}
```

`get_observations` will only change when `input$observations` changes.

Comment: that was absolutely what I needed - thanks so much! This seems like the kind of thing I would need to know for a lot of Shiny apps, so I'm glad it's a simple fix (: